# AspectJ : Issue when combining multiple pointcuts in @Around advice

Tags: aop, aspectj, execution, pointcuts

I'm a beginner in AspectJ so please guide me to resolve the issue happening as per the below approach.

```
    @Aspect
    public class TestAop {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.foo.ClassOne.*(..))")
    public void fooPoint()

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.cat.ClassTwo.*(..))")
    public void catPoint()

    @Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.roo.ClassThree.*(..))")
    public void rooPoint()

    @Around("fooPoint() || catPoint() || rooPoint()") 
    public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
    //do something like joint proceed and all
    }
```

When it is not working ?
If I combine all the three pointcuts with OR .

When it is working ?
If i keep only two pointcuts it is working.

Am I vioalating any rules of @around advice. Is it possible to have multiple execution/pointcuts?

Hoping for the answers...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had same problem but better solution IMO is(works for me):

```
@Aspect
public class TestAop {

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.foo.ClassOne.*(..)) || execution(public * com.packg.cat.ClassTwo.*(..)) || execution(public * com.packg.roo.ClassThree.*(..))")
public void fooPoint(){}

@Around("fooPoint()")
public Object myAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
//do something like joint proceed and all
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the above issue by creating different advice for each pointcut.
I just found an alternate solution, but i'm still not convinced with that.

```
@Aspect
public class TestAop {

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.foo.ClassOne.*(..))")
public void fooPoint()

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.cat.ClassTwo.*(..))")
public void catPoint()

@Pointcut("execution(public * com.packg.roo.ClassThree.*(..))")
public void rooPoint()

@Around("fooPoint()") 
public Object myFooAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
//do something like joint proceed and all
}

@Around("catPoint()") 
public Object myCatAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
//do something like joint proceed and all
}

@Around("rooPoint()") 
public Object myRooAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
//do something like joint proceed and all
}
```

Comment: It can be problematic, when some pointcuts happen to overlap (in above example they don't as they are in different packages).

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Advise Annotations if you want to use multiple pointcuts for a single advice.

For reference watch this video from JavaBrains:https://youtu.be/Clz78J7SBKQ?si=nGXFpPXlia4Uzf_J

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).